# Hidding low percent in donut chart

Tags: python, label, plotly, donut-chart

I have one donut chart that there are classes with low values in percent. I would like to hide these label of them from donut chart. With this way, as default plot, I think that they are messy.

My code:

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode()
#Dados (values)
dado_app_nascente = groupped_app_veg.loc[groupped_app_veg["app"] == "Entorno nascente", "area_ha"]
dado_app_rio = groupped_app_veg.loc[groupped_app_veg["app"] == "Margem de curso d'água", "area_ha"]

#Legenda ("labels")
label_app_nascente = groupped_app_veg.loc[groupped_app_veg["app"] == "Entorno Nascente", "class_name"].str.title()
label_app_rio = groupped_app_veg.loc[groupped_app_veg["app"] == "Margem de curso d'água", "class_name"].str.title()

#Cores ("marker": {"color"})
c_app_nascente = list(groupped_app_veg.loc[groupped_app_veg["app"] == "Entorno nascente", "color"])
c_app_rio = list(groupped_app_veg.loc[groupped_app_veg["app"] == "Margem de curso d'água", "color"])

fig = {
  "data": [
    {
      "values": dado_app_nascente,
      "labels": label_app_nascente,
      "domain": {"x": [0, .48]},
      "name": "area_entorno_nascente",
      #"hoverinfo":"label+percent+name",
      "textposition":"inside",
      "hole": .4,
      "type": "pie",
      "marker": {'colors': c_app_nascente},
      "showlegend": False
    },     
    {
      "values":dado_app_rio,
      "labels": label_app_rio,
      "textposition":"inside",
      "domain": {"x": [.52, 1]},
      "name": "area_margem_rio",
      #"hoverinfo":"label+percent+name",
      "hole": .4,
      "type": "pie",
      "marker": {'colors': c_app_rio},

    }],
  "layout": {
        "title":"PROPORÇÃO DE CLASSES: VEGETAÇÃO/USO DO SOLO",
        "width": 1000,
        "height": 500,
        "annotations": [
            {
                "font": {
                    "size": 18
                },
                "showarrow": False,
                "text": "NASCENTE",
                "x": 0.175,
                "y": 0.5
            },
            {
                "font": {
                    "size": 18
                },
                "showarrow": False,
                "text": "RIO",
                "x": 0.785,
                "y": 0.5
            },
            {
                "font": {
                    "size": 14
                },
                "showarrow": False,
                "text": "Área Preservação Permanente",
                "x": 0.555,
                "y": 1.135
            },
        ]
    }
}
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

[image: Donut Chart with]

Comment: iterate over your data beforehand and group segments less than (x%) into an "other" category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add attribute "textposition" to the data, it accepts both string and array. When "textposition" is "auto", the label displays as normal, and when it's "none", the label hides.

```
{
      "values": dado_app_nascente,
      "labels": label_app_nascente,
      "domain": {"x": [0, .48]},
      "name": "area_entorno_nascente",
      "textposition":"inside",
      "hole": .4,
      "type": "pie",
      "marker": {'colors': c_app_nascente},
      "showlegend": False,
      # vvv Here vvv
      "textposition": ['auto','auto','auto','auto','none','none','none'] 
    },
```

And we can generate the textposition array by calculating the percentage before hand:

```
def calculateTextpositions(values):
    total = sum(values)
    # Do not display percentages < 5%
    return map(lambda v: 'none' if float(v)/total < 0.05 else 'auto', values)
```

Then just use

```
"textposition": calculatetextpositions(dado_app_nascente),
```

Reference:
https://plot.ly/python/reference/#pie-textposition

Comment: Thank for your help. In my script have some problem. I put list(map...) and it works well.